# Inner view auto resize outer view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Nib setup: `TableViewCell`, `contentView` contains a `TextView`

Set vertical space and horizontal space constraints so `TextView` is flush against the `contentView` (top, bottom, leading and trailing, to equal and constant to 0).

When I add a Height constraint to the `TextView`, I get a constraint error. What I expected is the TableCell/ContentView to automatically expand when the `TextView` changes size. Is this not the way to resize `TableViewCells`?

[image: XCode screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a link to the answer you are looking for right here in Stack Overflow:
[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-within-uitableviewcell-for-dynamic-cell-layouts)

Comment: that's a great post but my question is different. I'm wondering why I can't set an inner view's height constraint to auto-set the outer view's height.

Comment: I believe it's because row height is not controlled by auto layout. In fact table view cell itself is not auto layout compatible either. But you can use auto layout inside your own view downwards from the contentView of the cell.